# Create .exe file to open .html document

Tags: windows, exe, dom

I need to create a .exe file that opens an .html document with the default browser.
In command prompt, `start myfile.html` works, but I don't know how to turn that into an .exe file.
How can I do that please?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you need an EXE. Just use the `ShellExecute` command in `[autorun]` in your autorun.inf. [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf#.5Bautorun.5D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite useless IMHO... Anyway use a .BAT file instead and use some app around there that [converts .BAT to .EXE](http://www.google.com/search?q=bat+to+exe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aes-ES%3aofficial&client=firefox-a).

Comment: .bat is easy. It's for a CD autorun. The client says he will die if he doesn't have this...

Comment: Did you read the whole answer? Use an app to convert the .BAT to .EXE.

Comment: @Francisc: shouldn't your question be more like, "how do I open a HTML with autorun.inf?" then?

Comment: I already did that, but the clients wants an Exe file... long story.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use a .bat file? Much less hassle than compiling an .exe. As well, in Windows, double-clicking the .html file would open it in the default browser anyways, so you're not gaining much.

Comment: He probably doesn't like bats => "I don't want .bat file"

Answer (score 1):

I'd echo the questions about *why* you'd want to do this, but if you really insist on doing it, it shouldn't be terribly difficult.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 
    if (argc !=2) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Usage: exec_html <html_file>", "Usage Error", MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }
    if ((int)ShellExecute(NULL, "open", argv[1], NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL) < 32) {
        MessageBox(NULL, argv[1], "Could not open file", MB_OK);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with a C or C++ compiler of your choice. If (as sounds like the case) you don't normally use either, the easiest way to go is probably get [Microsoft Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express), a free (as in beer) download.

Answer (score 1):

First download a `bat` to `exe` converter [here](http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html), then open notepad and type the following:

```
@echo off

start myfile.html

exit
```

Save it as whatever you want (`.bat`) and then start *bat to exe converter* and select the batch file and click the compile button.

This way works and too everyone wondering why you might want to do this, I infact have been looking everywhere for this and am glad I found it. I needed to make a ZIP file and inside I needed my game to be runable through an exe file and my game could only be run through HTML so I found this and have been able to do so. :)

Comment: The converter in the link contains a trojan
Trojan: Win32/Peals.F!plock detected - severe  - remove this software immediately

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with "open" as verb from C or C++.

Answer (score 0):

First download bat to exe converter from the following link:

http://download.cnet.com/Bat-To-Exe-Converter/3000-2069_4-10555897.html

Then open notepad and type the following:

`@echo off`

`start myfile.html`

`exit`

Save it as whatever you `want.bat` and then start bat to exe converter and select the batch file and click the compile button.

Now you get the exe file you wanted.